# Como usar los diseños de Adobe XD o Lunacy en un sitio web?

Tags: css, html5, css3

Soy nuevo en el mundo del diseño web y entre mis investigaciones vi que existen programas que crean interfaces. Según entendí entre mis lecturas esos programas no arrojan código para implementar en las paginas, la pregunta es la que pudieron ver en el titulo. Si no dan la opción para usar esos diseños entonces cual es su función?

Comment: O sea que el diseño de la web tambien podria hacerlo con ilustrator? A fin de cuentas yo tengo que ver como adapto el codigo a ese diseño cierto?

Comment: Recomiendo leas este hilo https://community.adobe.com/t5/adobe-xd/how-to-export-html-css-javascript-from-adobe-xd/td-p/9336611?page=1

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función de programas como AdobeXD o Figma es ayudar a visualizar el producto final antes de iniciar a escribir código. Le ayuda a los clientes a darse una idea de cómo va a ser la página o aplicación, y también les ayuda a quienes se van a encargar de los estilos a organizarse y planificar bien cómo van a organizar y escribir el código de la manera mas optima.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sm0qLEp3tUg Puedes revisar ese enlace, muestra una solucion importante a mi pregunta